# How do I get a Mule to return multiple rows from a JDBC query as a single transaction?

Tags: mule

If I have 100 rows in an Oracle table I'd like to receive one email with 100 rows in the body, instead I receive 100 emails, one for each row...  I thought the transactionPerMessage would do it (tooltip says, "if false, there will be a single transaction for the entire resultset") but it doesn't make a difference whether I set it to true or false.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:jbossts="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts/current/mule-jbossts.xsd ">
    <jdbc:oracle-data-source name="Oracle_Data_Source" user="test" password="test" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ora:1530/TEST.EXAMPLE.COM" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="Oracle Data Source"/>
    <jdbc:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="Oracle_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" transactionPerMessage="false" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="5000" doc:name="Database"/>
    <flow name="Ross_invoice_Workflow2Flow1" doc:name="Ross_invoice_Workflow2Flow1">
        <jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="GetUnprocessedInvoices" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="1000" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc:query key="GetUnprocessedInvoices" value="SELECT        INVOICE_NUMBER FROM            FIN.LHF_INVOICE_WORKFLOW&#13;&#10;WHERE        (STATUS_FLAG = 'N')"/>
        </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="mail.example.com" to="test@example.com" from="mule@example.com" subject="invoice test" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Mule create one message per row as it currently does, then use an aggregator to group messages by 100. You will also have to configure the time-out on the aggregator for the last group that will probably not reach 100 (unless your number of records is always a multiple of 100).

Comment: Thanks, David.  I'm still missing something, I added `<collection-aggregator timeout="10000" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>` just before the smtp endpoint but it is still generating one email per row.

Comment: Did you set the MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE property to 100?

Comment: nope, I didn't.  That worked!  This is ultimately what I used: '<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="100"/>   
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="1"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <collection-aggregator timeout="5000" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>'  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting transactionPerMessage to "false" on the connector should work if you ALSO set transactionPerMessage property to "true" on the endpoint and add a transaction like so:

```xml
<jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="GetUnprocessedInvoices" queryTimeout="-1"   pollingFrequency="1000" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc:query key="GetUnprocessedInvoices" value="SELECT        INVOICE_NUMBER FROM            FIN.LHF_INVOICE_WORKFLOW&#13;&#10;WHERE        (STATUS_FLAG = 'N')"/>
    <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    <property key="receiveMessageInTransaction" value="true"/>
</jdbc:inbound-endpoint>
```